# Is this ring right perfect?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let a ring $R$ be defined as $$R=\{ ae+\sum_ {\text{finite}} a_{ij}e_{ij} \mid i\leq j\},$$
where $a_{ij},a$ are real numbers, and $e,e_{ij}\in R\,  (i\leq j)$ are linearly independent over the field $\mathbb R$  with $e_{ij}e_{kl}=0\, (j\neq k),e_{ij}e_{jk}=e_{ik}, ee_{ij}=e_{ij}e=e_{ij},e^2=e,$ and the addition in $R$ is in the natural way, and the multiplication is distributive along with the above rules. Is the ring $R$ right perfect?

My try:

If we get $a=a_{ij}=0$  except for $a_{ii}=1$, for all $i$, then we derive from $R$ the infinite orthogonal linearly independent set $\{e_{11}, e_{22},\dots \}$ whose existence is in contrast with $R$ being a right perfect ring. (The set is infinite since $e_{ii}\neq e_{jj}$ via linearly independence of $e_{ij}$'s.)

Comment: When you write $e_{ij}e_{kl}=0$ $(i\neq j)$ do you actually mean $(j\neq k)$?

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry! You are right! And the question is edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: a ring with infinitely many pairwise orthogonal idempotents cannot be left or right perfect.

There is a characterization of perfect rings that requires families of mutually orthogonal idempotents to be finite that you can see in Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings* in the section on perfect rings.